# If $X_n(\omega)\leq Y_n(\omega)$, $Y_n\xrightarrow[]{p}0$, for every $\omega\in\Omega$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $\vert X_n(\omega)\vert \leq Y_n(\omega)$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$, $Y_n\xrightarrow[]{p}0$, then does $X_n\xrightarrow[]{p}0$?

My attempt:

Since $\vert X_n(\omega)\vert\leq Y_n(\omega)$, then $\{\omega : \vert X_n(\omega)\vert\geq \epsilon\}\subset \{\omega : \vert Y_n(\omega)\vert\geq \epsilon\}$

$\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}\{\omega : \vert X_n(\omega)\vert\geq \epsilon\}\leq \{\omega : \vert Y_n(\omega)\vert\geq \epsilon\}\rightarrow 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. The result then follows

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Yup, except the missing $\mathbb P$.